# Android: Send Longitude and Latitude after 60 seconds to the localhost server(WAMP)

Tags: android

I want to send the Longitude, Latitude, TimeStamp and the stonest wifi access point as JSON format to the server (WAMP- localhost) after every 60 seconds what is the best approach to do that? I would use AsyncTask but *AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)* can someone give short example for sending this data with another approach than AsyncTask?

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials about sending data from android to server ... try to apply one of them and we will help you if got errors .. i will give you two tutorial ..hope it helps

Comment: @Charef: can you please help me with the approach that I can use in my case because as I said I would use AsyncTask but it is not suitable in my case? which one can I use when I want to send data to the server every   60 seconds.

Comment: if i give you source code .. can you understand it easely ?

Comment: i can give you php code example and android java code... that i already use

Comment: i have question : why you don't want to use asyncTask?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. because the documentation says "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)" and I want to send the data after 60 seconds or I can use it?

Comment: if you get any problem just comment

Comment: @Charef: Can I use the AsyncTask if I want the data to be sent perdiocally after 60 seconds? because the documentation says "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

Comment: yes in the timer add new yourAsyncTasc().execute();

Comment: i use it already , with an interval of 3 seconds ..without facing any problem.. please tell me what is the problem i didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with these tutorials 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

after that here is how to repeate every 60 seconds

```
    boolean run=true; 
   Handler mHandler = new Handler();//sorry forgot to add this
...
...
      public void timer() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (run) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);//60000 milliseconds  which is 60 seconds
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                 //here you send data to server
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();}
```

call it like this to start it

```
  timer()
```

and to stop it just do

```
run=false;
```

Comment: what is mHandler in the code? I am getting this error"mHandler cannot be resolved" I think you forgot Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Comment: I did as you said but I am facing the problem that the compiler  reaches this line handler.post(new Runnable() it jumps back to while (run) and not enter the public void run() {new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);}

Comment: great ,happy to know that it works , if we don't help one another then who will help us , enjoy coding bro